# Eye white disappearing while looking up at an angle

Tags: modeling, mesh, unity

Any Unity users here? I have this issue where the white part of the eye partially disappears while looking up at an angle while in the Unity Edit. This never happened on this model until recently. The whole head parts were joined together at the time. On this version, I decided to separate them.

When I imported it to Unity, suddenly this happens. I checked the model again in Blender but no such issue occurs in the blender file. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a transparency sorting issue to me. Cannot say for sure without the files. The issue is that Unity has a hard time knowing which mesh is in front and which mesh is in the back. Unity looks at the pivots and tries to figure it out by comparing their positions in relation to the camera. Separarting the meshes did make it harder, because Unity now has to check which mesh is in front. You could try sort them manually using the Render Queue parameter on the default materials or adjust the mesh pivots for it to work better.

Comment: Sounds like I'll just revert back to the version with all of them grouped up.

Coz I dunno how to do those suggestions you just mentioned :(

Comment: the render queue you can only set within unity within the material settings of the respective mesh.

Comment: the mesh pivot can be adjusted using the Set Origin command. For further information check out the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html

Comment: I'll try that out then thanks. If you happen to know an easier way than this. Let me know. Thanks again! :)